# Here Navigate SDK Issue - "These credentials do not authorize access"

Tags: android, here-api

I am trying to migrate my project from Premium Sdk (Android) to Navigate Sdk Edition (Android) , but I have an issue when I am trying to load map scene (Normal_Day and Normal_Night map scheme) , in logcat I am getting (WARN) error: Download metadata failed, error=kAccessDenied, message='{"error":"Forbidden","error_description":"These credentials do not authorize access"}', and the map view stay blank. I have successfully sing up on here platform portal, registered app and project, and I have downloaded Navigate SDK for Android. Note, I don't have a issue with SDK initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Navigate Edition* for Android cannot be used with the credentials you obtain from the HERE platform. Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.10.4.0/dev_guide/index.html):

> For now, the *Navigate Edition* is only available upon request. Please
> [contact us](https://developer.here.com/help#how-can-we-help-you) to receive access including a set of evaluation
> credentials. Note that the HERE SDK package for the Navigate Edition
> is only available for customers who have signed a commercial contract
> via the HERE platform portal.

Answer (score 0):

I tried on 2 times (in last August and September) to contact Here in order to get information about the new Navigate licence. I don't get any reply. So, I try from the Stackoverflow site...

I'm still using the Premium edition and I would like to migrate. I also would like to know if the offline maps for Premium edition will be updated in the future or if the Premium will be compatible with the new maps.

I'm using the SDK for my personal use, and I use it time to time with one application installed on 2 or 3 devices.